# How to prevent removing zeros from a date string in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am converting a date into `y-m-d` to be added to MySQL:

```
let actDate = d.getDate();
let actMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
let actYear = d.getFullYear();
let newDob = actYear + '-' + actMonth + '-' + actDate;
console.log(newDob)
```

For some reasons, the `0`s is being removed from the date, so I can't compare it to other dates in my script.

E.g.: if the date is `2018-09-01`, it will be changed to `2018-9-1`.

Comment: Just add small method to format the date according to the format you want.

Comment: They are not being "removed". If anything, they are being _added_ in the default date format. `getMonth` and friends are giving you back a number; it's on you to make it into a zero-padded string. Or, you can use a library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to do date formatting for you. Finally, always compare like with like: dates with dates, formatted dates with equally formatted dates, arrays of numbers with arrays of numbers.

Comment: Its always better to compare dates with milliseconds from epoch.  Also method not  returns month date with 0. You have to format date your side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert your date to string and to keep 0 as leading in day and month, you can try this:

```
let newDob =        
(d.getFullYear()) + '-' + 
(d.getMonth() > 8 ? (+d.getMonth() + 1).toString() : '0' + (+d.getMonth() + 1).toString()) + '-' + 
(d.getDate() > 9 ? d.getDate() : '0' + d.getDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about IE support (or you want to use a polyfill just for IE), you can do this with using [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```
const actDate = `${d.getDate()}`.padStart(2, '0');
const actMonth = `${d.getMonth() + 1}.padStart(2, '0');
const actYear = d.getFullYear();
const newDob = actYear + '-' + actMonth + '-' + actDate;
console.log(newDob)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure if you have tried [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html#es6) Library. It is an extremely Small Library in Size when compared to other contemporary Libraries like Moment , but provides a very rich API. You can even get formatted Dates for SQL

Check this out: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-toLocaleString

Specially if you are using in the context of Angular6 with its ability to Tree Shaking.

P.S: Helps writing Code where you are not stitching together string literals

Answer (score 0):

Just create one function to remove leading zero.

```
let s = 09;
console.log(formatdate(s));

private formatdate(s){
s = s.toString().replace(/^0+/, '');
return s;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to remove them

Comment: Oh wrongly understood. Joe Belladonna his answer is perfect.